# how to redirect a url to other domain as it?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301, mod-alias

my primary domain is `makemyhome.com` and another one `mmh.com` now when a user click on the link `mmh.com/about` it should redirect to `makemyhome.com/about`.

when a user click on `mmh.com/contact` it should redirect to `makemyhome.com/contact`

right now my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

With the above code in htaccess doesn't work the way i want.

I need suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is almost correct. By adding the parameter %{REQUEST_URI} to the destination request your full request URI will also be redirected. For example: http://old.com/somepath/?some_get_param=some_get_val ==> https://new.com/somepath/?some_get_param=some_get_val

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com
RewriteRule ^ https://new.com%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.